# Add a date range to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have simple SQL Server view that I need to make amends to:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ApplicantStat]
    AS SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()), '') AS Pkid,
    AVG(ApplicationTime) AS 'AvgApplicationTime',
    AVG(ResponseTime) AS 'AvgResponseTime',
    CAST(ROUND(100.0 * count(case when [IsAccepted] = 1 then 1 end) / count(case when [IsValid] = 1 then 1 end), 0) AS int) AS 'AcceptRate'
    FROM [Application]
```

It works as planned, but I need to add a date range to it. It's not quite as simple as Where > this date and  < that date, instead I need to create a range.

Suppose I have a **'CreatedOn'** date in my Application table. I want to be able to include all rows from the last full day (yesterday) and work back 30 days (inclusive).

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
where CreatedOn between cast(getdate()-30 as date) and cast(getdate()-1 as date)
```

Please notice `CAST` is used, it is because to get the full day ignoring the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
where MyColumn between dateadd(dd, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and dateadd(dd, -30, convert(date, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit beyond the scope of this question, but maybe useful to some. I like this way of creating a table with date range, to use in queries:

```
USE MyDataBase

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '2014-01-01'  -- << user input >> --
SET @EndDate  = '2036-12-31'  -- << user input >> --

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Date
IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Date') IS NULL CREATE TABLE #Date (DateOne DATE)

INSERT INTO #Date VALUES (@StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Date

SELECT DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate) AS Date

SET @StartDate = DATEADD (DD, 1, @StartDate)

END

SELECT * FROM #Date
```

Comment: Adjusting this into a procedure that more complex queries can build on is super helpful. You win my heart today <3

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just stick a `WHERE` with a `BETWEEN` clause on the end.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ApplicantStat]
    AS SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID()), '') AS Pkid,
    AVG(ApplicationTime) AS 'AvgApplicationTime',
    AVG(ResponseTime) AS 'AvgResponseTime',
    CAST(ROUND(100.0 * count(case when [IsAccepted] = 1 then 1 end) / count(case when [IsValid] = 1 then 1 end), 0) AS int) AS 'AcceptRate'
    FROM [Application]
    WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN GETDATE()-1 AND GETDATE()-30
```